# Deselect Individually in RShiny pickerInput

Tags: shiny

In RShiny, Is there an option in `pickerInput` that deselects values individually instead of **Deselect All** ? Although I figured there is an option in `selectizeInput` using `options = list(plugins = list('remove_button'))`, I can't seem to find such one in `pickerInput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you click again on selected one, it deselects.**

```
pickerInput(
   inputId = "Id094",
   label = "Select/deselect all options", 
    choices = LETTERS,
   options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE), 
    multiple = TRUE
)
```